# Why does my user have the email attribute that I added to the user model but not any of the other attributes that I added?

Tags: django, django-models

When adding on to `Django`'s contrib `User` model in the `forms.py` file of my user app, the `email` field that I copied from a tutorial works perfectly but the other attributes that I added do not seem to exist.

```py
    from django import forms 
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

    class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
        email = forms.EmailField()
        gradClass = forms.IntegerField(required=False)
        major = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
        dorm = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
        hometown = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
        interests = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
        bio = forms.CharField(max_length=300)

        class Meta:
            model = User
            fields = ['username', 'password1', 'password2', 'email',
            'gradClass', 'major', 'dorm', 'hometown', 'interests', 
            'bio',
            ]
```

When I request to see a `user` email in the shell, it shows me their email, but when I request `gradClass` for example, it tells me that the `user` does not have any attribute called `gradClass`. How do I fix this? Is there something I might be missing in my other files?

Comment: welcome to SO! Provide some more code for your question: how are you calling the attributes? what are the errors? etc It's impossible to tell you the wrong part with just this part of `models.py`

Comment: That's the form. Where is the model?

Comment: @DanielRoseman The model is just the User model that I imported from the django contrib although if it will help, here is my models.py from the User app

Comment: from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

Comment: Oh sorry not sure why it formatted like that. I'm new to Stack Overflow

Comment: So User doesn't actually have any of those fields. So how could this work? What are you expecting to happen?